# URLSession в background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, request

После PushNoficitaion, нужно Request отправить на сервер и обновить базу данных.

Все работает как часы, но сам URLSession по непонятным причинам через раз выкидывает -1005 internet connection error

Думаю что я как-то не так работаю с ним в background. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы после пуша гарантированно сработала функция и данные обновились.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: BRRequest.request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { JSONData, response, error  -> Void in
     //do something
})
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызывайте функцию обновления рекурсивно в случае ошибки.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Спасибо!